# how do i sort a list, while reordering a second list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am currently having a problem, which i have to sort a list of path. 
the file which the path lead to is named as such a-b-c.wav.

These path are given to a function which outputs two list,

a list of the sampled_sounds - (`raw_sounds`)

a list of the file_names_of_sampled_audio - (`data_name`).

The function:

```
def load_sound_files(file_paths):
    raw_sounds = []
    data_output = []
    data_name = []
    max = 0
    for fp in file_paths:
        y,sr = librosa.load(fp,sr=16000)
        X = librosa.util.frame(y, frame_length=400, hop_length=160)
        raw_sounds.append(X.T)
        if max < (X.shape)[1]:
            max = (X.shape)[1]
            print "New max " + str((X.shape)[1])
        index_file = list(find_all(fp,'/'))
        filename = fp[index_file[len(index_file)-1]+1:len(fp)-4]
        file_name = filename.split('-')
        file_name = file_name[1]+'-'+file_name[2]+'-'+file_name[0]
        data_name.append(file_name)
    return raw_sounds, data_name
```

The function start by sampling the audio.
After the audio has been sampled, is the name renamed to
b-c-a.wav.

The sampled audio is appended to the list `raw_sounds`
the new name is appended to list `data_name`.

The problem here is that i need to sort the list `data_name`
but at the same time ensure that the list with the `raw_sounds` is still listed correctly according to the name in `data_name`..

I guess i would have to implement sorting manually, example of the name:

```
mblw-b-an1 
mdcs2-b-an111 
mdcs2-b-an112 
mdcs2-b-an113 
mdcs2-b-an114 
mdcs2-b-an115 
fmjc-b-an116 
fmjc-b-an117 
fmjc-b-an118 
fmjc-b-an119 
fmjc-b-an120 
fjdn-b-an121 
fjdn-b-an122
```

How do i sort something like this, while also reordering raw_sound, so both entries in `data_name` and `raw_sounds` contains the correct data.

Edit:

The solution i ended up using was this:

```
def resort(data_names, raw_sounds):
    data_names_bak = data_names
    data_names_sorted = sorted(data_names)
    raw_sound_output = []
    for i in range(0,len(data_names)):
        index = data_names.index(data_names_sorted[i])
        raw_sound_output.append(raw_sounds[index])
    return raw_sound_output, data_names_sorted
```

I will keep this open, in case there is a builtin solution, that i didn't know of.

Comment: Does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668393/python-sorting-two-lists

Comment: We don't really need to know about paths, filenames, etc. It's not really relevant to the problem. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov thanks for the link.. I am not sure how i can't test it..  the data list is pretty huge..

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov Unfortunately it doesn't work.

`list1, list2 = (list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda pair: pair[0])))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (468,400) (288,400) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather have both in the same list as a tuple or use a dictionary

also if that `find_all` is what I think it is, then the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module have a function for just that

```
>>> import os
>>> test="/path/to/my_audio/file.wav"
>>> os.path.basename(test)
'file.wav'
>>>
```

then your function can be rewrite as

```
import os

def load_sound_files(file_paths):
    data_output = []
    max = 0
    for fp in file_paths:
        y,sr = librosa.load(fp,sr=16000)
        X = librosa.util.frame(y, frame_length=400, hop_length=160)
        if max < (X.shape)[1]:
            max = (X.shape)[1]
            print "New max:", (X.shape)[1]
        file_name = os.path.basename(fp)[:-4].split('-')
        file_name = file_name[1]+'-'+file_name[2]+'-'+file_name[0]
        data_output.append( (file_name,X.T) )
    data_output.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    return data_output
    #return [ x[1] for x in data_output], [ x[0] for x in data_output  ]
    #use the commented return instead for obtain the lists with each 
    #part individually
```

also notice that you can use negative indexes `some_list[-n]` which is equivalent to `some_list[len(some_list)-n]`

---

with the suggestions of *EvensF*, you can include the file extension and/or work with files which have extension of different length like .midi, to mention one, without needed to modify the code. Like this for instance

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext( os.path.basename(fp) )
file_name = "{0[1]}-{0[2]}-{0[0]}".format(name.split("-")) + ext
```

(that way you don't need to later add the extension, or worry about what that is later in case you have multiples ones)

Comment: Your answer mirrors what I had in mind except for a few minor details: I think the original poster wanted the filename without the extension (`os.path.basename(fp)[:-4]`). You could have used `os.path.splitext()` for that. And the new filename (`file_name[1]+'-'+file_name[2]+'-'+file_name[0]`) could have been reconstructed with a formating string (`file_name = "{0[1]}-{0[2]}-{0[0]}".format(file_name)`) but like I said this is minor.

Comment: @EvensF nice points, I always forget the full power of str.format

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you just want two sort the to lists:

```
zipped_list = zip(data_names, raw_sounds)
zipped_list.sort(key=lambda (data_names, raw_sounds): data_names)
```

This gives you a sorted zipped list.

```
data_names, raw_sounds = zip(*zipped_list)
```

can undo the zipping.

---

If you use python 2.x consider using `itertools.izip` to work with iterator instead of lists.