# Sorting multiple lists using position of data from first list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a dynamically-populated list that when it's built, the data is passed into creating a stacked bar chart. With the data in the list sorted, so also the chart.

```
list: [
    ['Completion Date', 'New', 'NW-New', 'NW-Info', 'NW-Dec', 'NS-Modify', 'SN-Mod', 'VW-NwClter', 'NW-Del', 'VW-ModClter'],
    ['10/15/2017', 1,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/16/2017', 5,   8, 3,   2, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/17/2017', 1,   9, 0,  29, 3, 3, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/18/2017', 4,  44, 0,  11, 1, 0, 2,  0, 0],
    ['10/19/2017', 4,  39, 0,   0, 1, 0, 0,  1, 0],
    ['10/20/2017', 3,   2, 0,   0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 6],
    ['10/21/2017', 0,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 2,  0, 0],
    ['10/22/2017', 0,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/23/2017', 1,  67, 0,  85, 3, 2, 0,  1, 0],
    ['10/24/2017', 2,  25, 1,   4, 5, 0, 0,  1, 1],
    ['10/25/2017', 4,  65, 0,  11, 5, 0, 0, 11, 1],
    ['10/26/2017', 7,  40, 0,   0, 6, 0, 0,  2, 0],
    ['10/27/2017', 2,  37, 0, 115, 2, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/28/2017', 2,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/29/2017', 0,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/30/2017', 5,  53, 0,   0, 3, 0, 0,  1, 0],
    ['10/31/2017', 1,  30, 0,  19, 3, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['11/01/2017', 6, 106, 0,   2, 1, 0, 0,  1, 1],
    ['11/02/2017', 5,  74, 0,  10, 0, 0, 0,  9, 0]
]
```

The data in the first list matches that in the other lists, completion date goes with the date and the strings in the first list goes with the other data respectively.

I wanted a situation where if the string on the first list is sorted alphabetically, then the data matching its index position on the other list changes to the new position of the sorted string. Note the first data string completion date and the respective dates remain same.

I did some research and saw some examples but they were relative to two lists. Like an example of sorting using zip. Any ideas will be welcomed.

Comment: Where is the other list? You've shown just one.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ OP is presumably referring to the two lists within the mega-list provided. I'm not really sure what the goal is here though.

Comment: its a nested list there s outer list which is empty [ and an inner list [ hence [[ and in the inner list contains other list

Comment: Prettified your data. Can you show code of your attempt?

Comment: I attempted to do what others did like this example was so close except am making a mistake  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668393/python-sorting-two-lists) i understood i needed to start from index of 1 but this was a hard coded list and mine is dynamically populated so i cant use a named list like they have on there. Thanks aaron it looks better.

Answer (score 0):

As you asked:

> if the string on the first list is sorted alphabetically, then the
>   data matching its index position on the other list changes to the new
>   position of the sorted string.

You can take help and hint from this solution and modify it according to your need:

```
list1=[
    ['Completion Date', 'New', 'NW-New', 'NW-Info', 'NW-Dec', 'NS-Modify', 'SN-Mod', 'VW-NwClter', 'NW-Del', 'VW-ModClter'],
    ['10/15/2017', 'second', 'third', 'forth',   'fifth', 'sixth', 'seven', 'eight',  'nine', 'ten'],
    ['10/16/2017', 5,   8, 3,   2, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/17/2017', 1,   9, 0,  29, 3, 3, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/18/2017', 4,  44, 0,  11, 1, 0, 2,  0, 0],
    ['10/19/2017', 4,  39, 0,   0, 1, 0, 0,  1, 0],
    ['10/20/2017', 3,   2, 0,   0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 6],
    ['10/21/2017', 0,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 2,  0, 0],
    ['10/22/2017', 0,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/23/2017', 1,  67, 0,  85, 3, 2, 0,  1, 0],
    ['10/24/2017', 2,  25, 1,   4, 5, 0, 0,  1, 1],
    ['10/25/2017', 4,  65, 0,  11, 5, 0, 0, 11, 1],
    ['10/26/2017', 7,  40, 0,   0, 6, 0, 0,  2, 0],
    ['10/27/2017', 2,  37, 0, 115, 2, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/28/2017', 2,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/29/2017', 0,   0, 0,   0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['10/30/2017', 5,  53, 0,   0, 3, 0, 0,  1, 0],
    ['10/31/2017', 1,  30, 0,  19, 3, 0, 0,  0, 0],
    ['11/01/2017', 6, 106, 0,   2, 1, 0, 0,  1, 1],
    ['11/02/2017', 5,  74, 0,  10, 0, 0, 0,  9, 0]
]


track={index:value for index,value in enumerate(list1[0])}  #create a dict for keep tracking of old index


sorted_list=sorted(list1[0])  #sorting the first sub_list which have headers


for item in list1[1:]:
    right = [0] * len(item)
    for index,value in enumerate(item):
        if index in track:
            index_no=sorted_list.index(track.get(index))     #sorting other than first sub_list according to sorted first sub_list
            right[index_no]=value

    print(right)
```

output:

```
['10/15/2017', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'nine', 'forth', 'third', 'second', 'seven', 'ten', 'eight']
['10/16/2017', 1, 2, 0, 3, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0]
['10/17/2017', 3, 29, 0, 0, 9, 1, 3, 0, 0]
['10/18/2017', 1, 11, 0, 0, 44, 4, 0, 0, 2]
['10/19/2017', 1, 0, 1, 0, 39, 4, 0, 0, 0]
['10/20/2017', 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 6, 0]
['10/21/2017', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
['10/22/2017', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['10/23/2017', 3, 85, 1, 0, 67, 1, 2, 0, 0]
['10/24/2017', 5, 4, 1, 1, 25, 2, 0, 1, 0]
['10/25/2017', 5, 11, 11, 0, 65, 4, 0, 1, 0]
['10/26/2017', 6, 0, 2, 0, 40, 7, 0, 0, 0]
['10/27/2017', 2, 115, 0, 0, 37, 2, 0, 0, 0]
['10/28/2017', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
['10/29/2017', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['10/30/2017', 3, 0, 1, 0, 53, 5, 0, 0, 0]
['10/31/2017', 3, 19, 0, 0, 30, 1, 0, 0, 0]
['11/01/2017', 1, 2, 1, 0, 106, 6, 0, 1, 0]
['11/02/2017', 0, 10, 9, 0, 74, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```